# Retrieving user profile data from firebase and displaying

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Im creating user profile in firebase with this code:

```
username: string
msgnumber: number
level: number

constructor(private fire:AngularFireAuth,private db :AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

}

createProfile() {

    this.fire.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {

    this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).set({
        username: this.username,
        msgnumber: 0,
        level: 0
    }).then(() => 
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage));
    })
}
```

It is working. Now I'm trying to take the data of user and display it on their profile page.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})

export class ProfilePage {
    profileData: FirebaseListObservable<any>

    constructor(private fire:AngularFireAuth,private db :AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController) {

        this.fire.authState.subscribe(auth =>{
            this.profileData = this.db.list(`profile/${auth.uid}`);
            console.log(this.profileData);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but looks like it's not working. The problem is I guess I couldn't get the idea of object/list observables or generally how to retrieve data and how object observables are working. Checked internet and I guess people are using them to retrieve data?

database:
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b35IU.jpg)

Comment: Hey can you guide me from where to learn to fetch user profile into angular? any blog, videos or tutorials ?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right way. To finally retrieve the data you need to `subscribe` to the second observable which is assigned to `this.profileData`.

Like this:

```
this.fire.authState.subscribe(auth => {
  // subscribe to the observable
  this.db.list(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(profile => {
    console.log(profile);
  });
});
```

Now to avoid the nesting you can make use of the `switchMap` operator which rxjs offers you.

The result looks like this:

```
this.profileData$ = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.list(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges());
this.profileData$.subscribe(profile => console.log(profile))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.i tried this and got _this.db.list(...).subscribe is not a function error. do you have any idea  ?

Comment: which version of `angularfire2` are you using?

Comment: latest one.5 i guess

Comment: ok, then you need to use one of angularfire2 actions too. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks i just read the doc and noticed the difference.do u know how can i display profileData on html ?   <ul *ngFor="let profile of profileData | async">
                                      <li> {{ profile.level}}:{{ profile.username}}:{{profile.msgnumber}} </li>
                                    </ul> triying somethng like that but not working

Comment: Notice: if you use the `async` pipe you no longer need to `subscribe` by your own. So you can get rid of this line `this.profileData$.subscribe(profile => console.log(profile))` and just do `*ngFor="let profile of profileData$ | async"`

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to get the user for two days. Your answer worked. Thanks