# How to retrieve and display data relevant to a particular user profile from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to angular. I somehow learned how to get data from firebase to my angular pages by following many tutorials. But I don't understand how to retrieve data to a particular user profile when that user gets logged in to his profile.

these are some of the ones that i tried out to get this thing working. but i got failed in all those attempts
[Retrieving user profile data from firebase and displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853450/retrieving-user-profile-data-from-firebase-and-displaying)
[How to display clicked user profile data in a different component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583627/how-to-display-clicked-user-profile-data-in-a-different-component)

**venue-profile.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-venue-profile',
  templateUrl: './venue-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venue-profile.component.scss']
})
export class VenueProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  users:Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db:AngularFirestore) {
    this.users = db.collection('register_user').valueChanges();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**venue-profile.component.html**

```js
<div class="main-content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="ml-1" *ngFor = 'let user of users | async'>{{ user.user_name }}</h1>
        <div class="row">  



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you get the response in the chrome dev tools network tab? did you check it?

Comment: when you mean user profile, are you looking to get the user data that is stored during user authentication?

Comment: @BearNithi No it doesn't show anything in response. anyway im not that much family with that network tab. I checked the console, it shows 5 arrays have been recieved from database relevant to 5 documents in that collection

Comment: @KevinRED Yes you got it right!

Comment: ok in that case i think currentUser is enough? Did you used it? Or authStateChnaged

Comment: @KevinRED as i am new to this, i have no idea about how i should use it. Can u please come up with some codes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406203/8437740

Answer (score 0):

you can get data from firebase using `snapshotChanges()` method.
here I'm attached example

app.component.ts

```js
// import service
import { CrudService } from './services/crud.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public crudService: CrudService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {

    //get data from crud service
    this.crudService.getFFList().subscribe(data => {
      this.fflist = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ffdata: e.payload.doc.data(),
        };
      })
    });

  }


}
```

crud.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CrudService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
  
  //method for get data from firebase with collection name ff_list
  getFFList() {
    return this.firestore.collection('ff_list').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Short Form</th>
  <th>Full Form</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let ff of fflist">
    <td>{{ff.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ff.ffdata.ff_short}}</td>
    <td>{{ff.ffdata.ff_full}}</td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="delete(ff.id)">Delete</button>
      <button (click)="editFF(ff.id,ff.ffdata)">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```